# Deactivate UILongPressGestureRecognizer after certain seconds?

Tags: ios, objective-c, long-press

How can i deactivate my UILongPressGestureRecognizer automatically after certain seconds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for set time interval in -viewDidLoad :

```
NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0f target:self selector:@selector(removeGesture) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

in selector method:

```
-(void)removeGesture
{
    [self.view removeGestureRecognizer:longGesture1];
}
```

after 5 seconds  UILongPressGestureRecognizer remove from view and will deactive

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(onTick:) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.0/*your delay time*/];


-(void)onTick:(id)sender
{
    for (UIGestureRecognizer *recognizer in self.view.gestureRecognizers)        {

         if([recognizer isKindOfClass:[UILongPressGestureRecognizer class]])      {
                  [self removeGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
          }
   }
}
```

Hope this helps.